# Japanese characters are not showing (blank)

Tags: jquery, jsp, internationalization, cjk

I want to show a select box which shows language types as their own languages. For example, Korean will be displayed as `한국어`. The other languages are OK, but Japanese characters are showing as blank even though it has its value `日本語` well in the inspector when I push the `F12` button.

Also, it shows `日本語` well in other environments such as `cloud`. I have tried google encoding extension to change encoding type `UTF-8` which ended up nothing changed. And I have added the below code on the top of jsp source but also failed to fix the problem.

`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

DevTools(F12) - OK

[image]

Screen select box from local PC - NG

[image]

Screen from cloud PC - OK

[image]

[Unicode(UTF-8) extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZVQs.png)

Comment: It's very hard to help you without being able to see any code.

Comment: What is `font-family` on that `<select>`?

Comment: That was really helpful. When I changed the font-family, Japanese characters were displayed well. but still, I don't understand why it is ok only for the cloud screen, even tho the codes are same. And now I need to figure out what fonts I can use for our web-page in the aspect of font copyright. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<select name="selectact" id="selectact" style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">
        <option value="page" selected="selected">网 页</option>
        <option value="news">新 闻</option>
        <option value="trade">行 业</option>
        <option value="area">区 域</option>
        <option value="web">网 站</option>
        <option value="image">图 片</option>
        <option value="mp3">MP3</option>
        <option value="flash">Flash</option>
        <option value="bbs">论坛</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Comment: I think he/she wanted to tell me about font-family and it helped me a lot! thanks!